# How to create multiple shortcuts of files from one folder?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, url-shortening, windows, mp3

Windows 10, mp4/mp3 files.
As well related question: how to/can shortcut change there's 'open from' direction based on original file changing its direction?

Comment: This question is not about a web application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select all of the files you want to have a shortcut,

Then right-click on them, and go to "Send to"

[image]

Then press on Desktop (create shortcut)

---

If you want to make the shortcuts be made in the same folder as the original file then instead press "Create shortcut" 2 buttons beneath the "Send to" button.

If you do this the shortcut will be made within the folder

---

Another way would be to copy what you want to create shortcuts of...

[image]

Then where ever you want to paste your shortcuts just press "paste shortcut"

[image]

Comment: thank you! better then no option, yet need to specific folder, and question about 'how to/can shortcut change there's 'open from' direction..'.

Comment: I made an edit to show that you can also send the shortcut to the folder the original file is as well as sending it to the desktop